# How to know when @Input changes?

Tags: angular

I am passing different `id` from the parent component to the child component.

// **parent component**

```
<child-component id={{id}}></child-component>
```

// **child component**

```
@Input('id') id:string;
```

How to get an event when `id` changes? I want to run a function when `id` changes in the child component.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `ngOnChanges(changes)`. It's called when input values change.

It's called once just before `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a setter. From my experience neither setter or ngOnChanges are called when @Input() is on an array as the reference of array does not change in that case. Luckily ngDoCheck is called if array items change.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html